# Updating Jenkins on GKE with Helm Chart - Best Practices

Tags: jenkins, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I have a Jenkins Helm Chart deployed on Google Cloud GKE. I'm interested in keeping the Jenkins installation up-to-date with the latest plugins. However, I'm unsure about the best approach:

1. Updating the Jenkins Image:

Currently, I'm considering simply updating the Jenkins image within the existing Helm Chart to one that includes the desired plugins.

Question: Is this a recommended practice for updating Jenkins on GKE with Helm? Are there potential drawbacks or security concerns associated with this approach?

2. Helm Upgrade vs. Direct GKE Deployment:

I understand that using helm upgrade might require modifying the values.yaml file due to potential changes in the chart version. Is there a way to avoid these changes and simply update the image directly through GKE deployment commands?

I appreciate any insights and recommendations on maintaining a secure and efficient Jenkins update process on GKE using Helm.